# Resharper unit tests DISPLAY order

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, resharper

Is there a way to customize the order in which Resharper displays the unit tests? I do not need that they run in any specific order. I just need that they be displayed in the same order as I define them in the test class and not e.g. in alphabetic order.

Thanks,

Comment: Just to add: NUnit's `[Order(x)]` attribute can be used to define the order in which tests are run, but R# always displays tests in alphabetical order. For integration tests you may want to look at certain tests first and order might matter.